# Customization option for file info blob in nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, files, info

Is there any way to customize the location/placement or the content of the info bubble?

The reason I ask is that the popup bubble usually covers exactly the file I'm working on and I'd rather have the info bubble somewhere else.

I tried looking for this on the usual channels but it's really hard to filter out all the results with the generic search terms used. Also, I'm not sure what this info bubble is actually called.

A search in `dconf` yielded no results.

Any clue would be appreciated.

[image]