# Nautilus: File description tooltip occludes file info when viewing bottom file

Tags: nautilus

When I click a file in Nautilus, a tooltip appears at the bottom-right of the window, displaying the file's name and size. This info is on top on the file's description columns, such as "size", "date modified", so I can never see them for the bottom file.

Is there a way to remove the tooltip, or make it appear elsewhere?
here's an example image of the occluding tooltip:

[image: occluding tooltip]

Clarification: I am *not* interested in a solution of sorting the files by another order. This will interrupt my workflow.

BTW, It appears that a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873340/customization-option-for-file-info-blob-in-nautilus) has been asked as well and not answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the mouse over the tooltip for it to disappear temporarily.

[image: hover over tooltip animation]

---

As an alternative you could [replace Nautilus with Nemo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481742/how-to-replace-nautilius-with-nemo-in-gnome-3?rq=1), which has the old-style status bar instead.

Comment: That's weird, that doesn't work for me. The tooltip remains in its place.

Comment: I use 16.04 / Nautilus 3.14.3

Comment: This is exactly my setting.

Comment: Works the same when I switch to Ambiance theme ... so not theme-dependent

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the tooltip hides when the cursor moves over it. There seems to be a bug: whenever multiple tabs are open, the tooltip is no longer hidden.

There are possible workarounds:

- Only use a single tab
- Clear the selection by navigating away and back
- Clear the selection by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>